# Closing refrigerator's door causes freezer's door to stay open

Tags: repair, doors, refrigerator

The problem with the freezer door is that when the refrigerator's door is pushed closed, the door of the freezer slightly opens and stays open without re-closing and sealing itself properly, leaving a gap. It seems to be due to even the slightest closing as something does not absorb shocks properly. Similar thing with refrigerator's door but it worries me less as it closes and seals itself. It's actually the freezer's door which I am concerned more about:

[image]

See this in action on YouTube: http://youtu.be/5fs35-deVV0

There are no screws holding gasket and it seems to be stretched across door's frame.

I am concerned because as long as door opened, I hear fridge constantly working and leaving door opened for half day results in freezer's inside becoming wet. After closing door and looking inside next day I get to see products covered in snow/ice? and layer of ice on fridge's left and right sides, and especially freezer's ceiling.

If you think about misalignment then there is a bit but I have no idea how to realign. And if I did realign, you think doors would be absorbing shocks properly without opening?

What are your thoughts gentlemen? Thanks.

Comment: How old is it? If its new enough, I'd check with the manufacturer to see if this is a warranty issue.

Comment: @Comintern The brand is Haier and it is not new. It's more like almost 4 years old and out of warranty. I am not even sure distributor can locate replacement part for it. Do you think I could find parts on eBay?

Comment: Not sure it's a parts issue, but its always best to check the easy solution first ;-). From the video, it looks like they seal properly but you're getting overpressure from the other compartment door closing. Not sure what would cause that, but I'd check to make sure the condensate drain isn't blocked.

Comment: And blocked condensate drain could cause that pressure? How can it become blocked and how can I check this?

Comment: If it is a pressure problem, that's the only thing I can think of that would relieve air pressure inside.  The drain hole should be at the bottom of the compartment. Check this link: http://homeguides.sfgate.com/unplug-drain-refrigerator-21433.html

Comment: I changed "fridge" to freezer. Most people think fridge and refrigerator are the same thing, "freezer" causes the description to make more sense. If the door is misaligned, it should be able to be corrected by loosening the hinge screws and moving the hinge slightly. Be sure there is nothing inside that might be pushing against the doors. It does seem something is blocked, there shouldn't be so much pressure as to force open the opposite door.

Answer (score 1):

Before going out and buying new rubber seals, simply extend the fridge front legs about one inch, tipping the fridge back so that the doors will swing shut by gravity. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Hmm.. I think this answer was edited because earlier it mentioned to lower legs. Yes, it was by Daniel and now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a door out of alignment to me, and it's just minor enough to only take a slight change in pressure to release the bottom corner's seal. The screws holding the door's current alignment tend to be concealed by the gasket. So you pull the gasket back to reveal the screws, loosen them all around the door, pull the top corner out to change the alignment, and then tighten just the corners first to check your work. Once you are happy with the alignment, you tighten the remaining screws.